Why is my external HDD not detected anymore in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS?
Recently I've installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and I've connected my external HDD and it was detected but today something happened and it didn't recognize it at all. I've tried turning off the computer and reconnecting it again but it didn't work. Tried to connect it to another computer and it works so the problem isn't with the hdd but something with the os(ubuntu) but I can't seem to figure out what exactly. Can somebody help me?
Tried sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA THNSNK25
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 61D1FEFA-18BA-424D-8696-F3076A4D4D30

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 500115455 500111360 238.5G Linux filesystem

When I run this command sudo inxi -F it shows me only my internal SSD:
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 58.84 GiB (24.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: THNSNK256GCS8 SATA 256GB
    size: 238.47 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 233.67 GiB used: 58.84 GiB (25.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2


Connect the disk, open a terminal, run in it: sudo fdisk -l, sudo inxi -F. Copy the outputs, edit your post and paste them into it.

I've done that but it doesn't detect it at all.

Is external drive a Windows format like NTFS? If so, did Windows turn hibernation or fast startup on which sets hibernation flag? Or does it need chkdsk? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

@oldfred I thinks it's NTFS, yes. But the first time I connected it worked. When the hdd is not used for some time it goes into sleep mode I think and after that it disappears from Files. About the hibernation I'll check.

It seems to be a hardware problem. Since the disk works in another machine, it is either the port or the connection cable (try using another port and another cable)

@kyodake I've tried all those things and it doesn't seem to be a hardware problem.

thank you anyway for trying to help!
